# prior vs previous vs late vs former

Tags: exam-questions

I'd like to ask which one fits best when we talk about a prime minister?

> As a______ prime minister, his views are treated with respect when he
>   is interviewed.

1.prior

2.previous

3.late

4.former

---

I know prior and previous  virtually overlap , and former is opposed of latter but it seems like all these words have been used in this context..Is there any point in this question?

Comment: Are you certain you can't rule out any of those words? What does "As a late prime minister" mean to you? Does it fit with the rest of the sentence? If prior and previous are about the same meaning, and only one word can be chosen, maybe neither of them fit if you look more closely at their definitions?

Comment: As a side note, I think the sentence is incorrect no matter which word you choose, because it contains what's called a [dangling modifier](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/danglingmodifier.htm).  Look at it carefully: "As a (former) prime minister, his views are..."  His views are a former prime minister?!?!   What's the subject of the sentence?  *His views*.  So the prepositional phrase is not describing the subject.  More correct would be "As (or *because*) he is a former prime minister, his views are..."

Comment: @stangdon While I agree with the assessment, this is a mistake that a native speaker might make as well.

Comment: @Era - To be sure!  But just because native speakers make it doesn't mean it isn't a mistake!  I mean, I see a depressing number of native speakers write things like "Your my favorite person" too...

Comment: @ColleenV The word late is used also for people passed away so it would not be used probably in this context but the thing is when I searched them results show up with the rest of the word as previous/prior or former prime minister on the internet.

Comment: The modifier is dangling, but not enough so to cause confusion unless you look for it.

Comment: @Mrt I'm just trying to show you that when you're trying to figure out the answer, you should also look at all of the context that you have. "Late" prime ministers usually don't give good interviews! :)

Comment: @ColleenV I agree with you. I think they cannot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first glance, there does not seem to be much difference between them.

> prior(adj) : existing or coming before in time, order, or importance
>
> previous(adj): existing or occurring before in time or order
>
> former(adj): having previously been a particular thing
>
> late (adj): 1) living comparatively recently now deceased)
>   2) being something or holding some position or relationship recently but not now

"Prior" is rarely used about people: it is normally used about appointments, arrangements, experience and criminal convictions.

"The previous" is useful if you want to talk about the persons(s) immediately preceding the incumbent in a role: "a previous" is possible, but is less common, particularly when used about people in roles.

Prime Minister is a position in the government, so this favours "former" (having being something) and "late" (holding some position recently). I had not come across this definition of "late" until I checked the dictionary: I assumed that it only meant "recently deceased". It is probably best to rule out "late" because most people would understand it as "As a dead prime minister".

To sum up, the words do have similar meanings, but usage is different. Former is definitely the strongest candidate, as it concerns a person in a role, with previous coming a not-very-close second. Check out this [google ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a%20previous%20prime%2Ca%20former%20prime&year_start=1980&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20previous%20prime%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20former%20prime%3B%2Cc0)

Is there any point in it as an exam question? It depends on the level of the students. For native English speakers, the correct answer seems obvious, though it's pretty difficult to explain why. If English is not your first language, it must certainly be a difficult question.

Comment: I did a quick check of NGrams between 'prior _role_' and 'previous _role_', for example, previous student versus prior student, and the only phrase I came across that had any significant usage was "prior tenant". I think that may be primarily a legal use. After 1850, previous is much more common.

Answer (score 1):

"Former" would probably be the most correct in the particular sentence. He was once a prime minister, but is no longer.  The use of the word "former" emphasizes the previous status of this person.

"Previous" would be the next best, though "As a previous prime minister" is somewhat odd sounding.  The use of "previous", to my ear, puts more emphasis on the sequence of holders of the prime minister positions, rather than the person itself.  It would be more common to say "As *the* previous prime minister" (if he were in fact the most recent one).

"Prior" is similar, though it is much more often used to refer to a sequence of events rather than status.  For example

> He was prime minister prior to the election where his party lost favor.

"Late" should not be used.  "Late" when describing a person who is not arriving after a scheduled time, means they have died.  For example

> Even after 15 years he still mourns his late wife.